# How to change Android DatePicker month navigation chevron/arrow color

Tags: android, android-theme, material-components-android, android-datepicker, material-dialog

I am using the [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/main/documentation/DATETIME.md) component of the Material Dialog library. I want to change the color of the left arrow "<" and also the text color of the future day number (Marked in red color in the attached image). I am able to update TimePicker but no luck with DatePicker.

[image: Date Time Picker Alert]